# AngularJS ng-if inside ng-repeat does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code:

```
<body  ng-controller="QueryCntl">

<div>
    <h1> Target:{{target}}</h1>         
</div>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mytableCtrl">    

<div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>

<div id="menuList">
    <ul class="menuNav">
        <li class="menuList_Slide" ng-repeat="x in names">
            <div>               
                <a href="category.html?categoryid={{x.id}}">{{ x.category }}</a>
            </div>

            <div ng-if="{{target}} == {{x.id}}"> //Display subcategory if true
                <ul id="subCategories">
                    <li>
                        <a href="category.html?subcategoryid={{x.id}}">Childid should be displayed</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [], function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
    function QueryCntl($scope, $location) {
        $scope.target = $location.search()["categoryid"];       
    }
    app.controller('mytableCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("api/topCategories")
        .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});                        
    });

</script>
```

I want to display only 1 subcategory if {{target}} is equal to {{x.id}}. But for now it prints everything... {{target}} gets value from the url where ?categoryid=some_number and x.id is a value from DB. These values works fine in my code.

I would appreciate any help.

**EDIT: ng-if="target == x.id" does not help.**

Comment: I don't think the curly braces `{{ }}` are needed within `ng-if`. Try `ng-if="target == x.id"`.

Comment: If sdgluck's code Not working Means Your X.id is Passing Null .You May need check that Scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngIf` doesn't need to use `{{}}` - it's already an Angular expression:

```
div ng-if="target == x.id"
```

Comment: `<body  ng-controller="QueryCntl">`

Comment: I did it, but still all categories are displayed, not one.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solver:
I inserted

```
<base href="category.html">
```

in head tags and deleted bad script source.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to interpolate properties within the `ng-if` directive's conditional as Angular evaluates the complete expression against the scope already. Try this:

```
ng-if="target == x.id"
```

Answer (score 0):

ngIf directive expects an expression, so you don't need interpolation tags:

```
<div ng-if="target == x.id"> //Display subcategory if true
    <ul id="subCategories">
        <li>
            <a href="category.html?subcategoryid={{x.id}}">Childid should be displayed</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And one more thing: you are not initializing `$scope.target` because corresponding controller is outside of the `ng-app`. Remove `ng-controller="QueryCntl"` and add target initialization into `mytabeCtrl`:

```
app.controller('mytableCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.target = $location.search()["categoryid"];
    $http.get("api/topCategories")
    .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});                        
});
```

Comment: It still prints all subcategories... Every category has own id. In total 6. When I use ng-if="target == x.id" I want to display/show only one subcategory, not all at one time.

Comment: If i delete ng-controller="QueryCntl",  QueryCntl stops working, it gives me big error. I added $location in controller, but without ng-controller="QueryCntl" value it is not working. Anyway it still prints out all categories, not one.

Comment: Inject $location into `mytableCtrl `.

Comment: I did it. But it still prints all subcategories, not one which value is target = x.id

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in plunker? Create a simple demo with your code here http://plnkr.co/edit/42zzvoOFBcfifqG4SIyO?p=preview then it will be easy to help you.

Comment: So what can I say, how can I help you without seeing the problem. Try to identify what differs between plunker and your code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<div ng-if="{{target}} == {{x.id}}">
```

With:

```
<div ng-if="target == x.id">
```

The `ng-if` attribute should contain plain JavaScript, instead of those interpolation tags (`{{}}`).

This holds true for all `ng-` attributes.